# Regex for matching a string literal in Java?

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

I have an array of regular expressions strings. One of them must match any strings found in a given java file.

This is the regex string I have so far: `"(\").*[^\"].*(\")"`

However, the string `"Hello\"good day"` is rejected even though the quotation mark inside the string is escaped. I think what I have immediately rejects the string literal when it finds a quotation mark inside regardless of whether it is escaped or not. I need it to accept string literals with escaped quotes but it should reject `"Hello"Good day"`.

```
  Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(\").*[^\"].*(\")", Pattern.DOTALL);
  Matcher matcher = regex.matcher("Hello\"good day");
  matcher.find(0); //false
```

Comment: Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: You probably want to put a negative look-behind on the `"` character. But you will have a hard time dealing with comments.

Comment: Also you say '"Hello\"good day" is rejected' and then you say 'but it should reject "Hello"Good day"'. That means it's working.

Comment: *I need it to accept string literals with escaped quotes but it should reject `"Hello"Good day"`* - you must mean a regex like `String pat = "\"[^\\\\\"]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\""` and use it with `String#matches()`. EDIT: See what anubhava has just posted.

Comment: Do you need to worry about other escape sequences? `\n`, `\t`, `\u1234`?

Comment: I do not need to worry about other escape sequences or comments. Just the quote escape

Comment: Can you please try `String pat = "^(?:[^\"\\\\]|\\\\.|\"[^\\\\\"]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\")*$"`?

Comment: Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^(?:[^\"\\\\]|\\\\.|\"[^\\\\\"]*(?:\\\\.   [^\"\\\\]*)*\")*$", Pattern.DOTALL);
      Matcher matcher = regex.matcher("Hello\"good day");
      boolean result=matcher.find(0); //I tried this, and result is false

Comment: @pythonbeginner4556: Shouldn't it be false? It only has 1 double quote that is not escaped. Check [this demo](http://ideone.com/YM8If3). What if you reverse the logic? Will it work as expected then?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Java you can use this regex to match all escaped quotes between `"` and `"`:

```
boolean valid = input.matches("\"[^\"\\\\]*(\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\"");
```

Regex being used is:

```
^"[^"\\]*(\\.[^"\\]*)*"$
```

**Breakup:**

```
^             # line start
"             # match literal "
[^"\\]*       # match 0 or more of any char that is not " and \
(             # start a group
   \\         # match a backslash \
   .          # match any character after \
   [^"\\]*    # match 0 or more of any char that is not " and \
)*            # group end, and * makes it possible to match 0 or more occurrances
"             # match literal "
$             # line end
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mD0lI1/3)

Comment: Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"\\\\]*)(\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\"",   Pattern.DOTALL);
      Matcher matcher = regex.matcher("Hello\"good day");
      boolean result=matcher.find(0); //I get false when I use your regex string this way. How can I make it work

Comment: Slightly quicker if use cluster group instead of capture.